# SSH Fails at "kex_exchange_identification"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, osx

I'm trying to connect over ssh to an Ubuntu 18.04 VM running in VMWare on my local machine. Local machine has openssh server up and running.

Apple's default ssh binary fails connecting to VMs in VMWare as documented [here](https://communities.vmware.com/message/2778248#2778248). So, I installed ssh with homebrew and am attempting to use that instead.

On running ssh, it fails to connect and spits out the error:

```
kex_exchange_identification: write: Broken pipe
```

Running with verbose flags shows the following:

```
$ /usr/local/bin/ssh -vvv dev@[ip]
OpenSSH_8.0p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/[username]/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/[username]/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *
debug1: /Users/[username]/.ssh/config line 8: Applying options for *
debug1: /Users/[username]/.ssh/config line 11: Ignored unknown option "usekeychain"
debug1: Reading configuration data /usr/local/etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname [ip] is address
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to [ip] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: getpeername failed: Invalid argument
debug1: identity file /Users/[username]/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /Users/[username]/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
kex_exchange_identification: write: Broken pipe
```

My `~/.ssh/config` file contains the following:

```
Host *
    ServerAliveInterval 300
    ServerAliveCountMax 2
    TCPKeepAlive no
    IPQoS=throughput
    AddKeysToAgent yes
    IgnoreUnknown UseKeychain
    UseKeychain yes
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

I've tried restarting the ssh server on the VM to no avail. I haven't been able to find any information about the kex_exchange_identification error online.

Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: If you would remove '=' in your ssh_config ?

Answer (score 1):

`kex_exchange_identification: write: Broken pipe` is a message from the SSH client that the SSH server (sshd) disconnected during the key exchange (kex).

Check the logs on the VMware guest(s) for reasons why the SSH server is hanging up on you.  If they're Unix/Linux VMs, look in `/var/log/`, in files with names like `messages`, `syslog`, `auth`, and/or `authpriv`.